# How can you 'test' for grammatical properties in A Student's Introduction to English Grammar?

Tags: syntax, grammar, parts-of-speech, grammatical-category

According to the book A Student's Introduction to English Grammar (2005), grammatical terms, e.g., subject, object, noun, verb, adjective, etc. should not be defined by meaning, but by grammatical properties.

For example, an adjective has combinations of the following properties:

(1) functions as an attributive modifier or predicative complement

(2) can inflect for grade, e.g., better, harder; or form comparative and superlative adjective phrases, e.g., more interesting

(3) can be modified by adverbs like "very," or "too"

One thing I notice is that sometimes adjectives are easily identified with these properties because of the context.

For example, the word "hard" in "he is a very hard worker" is obviously an adjective because it is modified by "very" and it functions as an attributive modifier (or, more specifically, heads an adjective phrase that functions as an attributive modifier).

But sometimes adjectives are not easy to identify because the context barely provides anything for you.

For example, in the sentence "The rock is hard" the word "hard" has the only property of an adjective - functioning as a predicative complement.

In the book, the authors manipulate sentences like this to 'test' whether "hard" has any other properties of adjectives. They might add "very" to the sentence to see whether or not "hard" can be modified by "very.

However, sometimes I think they go too far.. Like, in this example from the answer key to the book, the authors try to 'test' whether "barking" can form a comparative phrase by putting it in a completely new sentence (as highlighted in Bold).

> 4. Which of the underlined words below are adjectives, which are verbs, and which are ambiguous between the two categories in the
>    examples given? Give evidence for your answers.

> Example: The dog is
> barking again.
> Answer: *Barking is a verb. It has a corresponding
> preterite form (The dog barked again), but doesn't have a comparative
> **(*Rex is more barking than Fido)**. It doesn't accept such modifiers as
> very (*The dog is very barking). It can't occur in predicative
> complement function: be in the example is the progressive auxiliary,
> and can't be replaced by such verbs as become and seem (*The dog seems
> barking).

Source:[http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/SIEG/exx_ch6.html](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/SIEG/exx_ch6.html)

So my question is: Are there restrictions on how you can 'test' for grammatical properties? Can I just put the word in question in any sentence to see if it has any other properties?

(I was advised by someone on the English Stackexchange to ask this question in this forum to get different perspectives)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/589670/15299

Comment: 1. Just for the record, H&P 2005 say the following (p. 112), "Syntactically, **prototypical adjectives** in English have the following three properties ..." (emphasis mine - A.B.). 2. Modification is also possible, *The rock is hard* cf.  *The rock is very hard.* etc.

Comment: @AlexB. OP mentions 2) themselves. Am I missing the thrust of your comment?

Comment: @Araucaria-him OP writes "For example, in the sentence "The rock is hard" the word "hard" has the only property of an adjective - functioning as a predicative complement", i.e. property 1).  I'm afraid I have to disagree with this assertion, "the only property". What about you?

Comment: @AlexB. I agree with what you say about H&P. But I also think the OP agrees with you too! What they mean to say is that *The rock is hard* only displays one property of being an adjective. They would agree that in *The rock is very hard* it displays two, but you have to add the *very*. It doesn't occur in the original example. So the OP is wondering how far from the original example we can diverge when testing properties that aren't evident in the original example. (I think)

Comment: @Araucaria-him I see. I think this question is based on a gross misunderstanding, **can** and **be** are verbs with a slightly different meaning, wouldn't you say so? I hope the OP can see this difference too (no pun intended). Just because e.g. adjectives "can be modified, usually by adverbs" (p. 112) does **not** mean that all adjectives are always modified so. The same goes for "can inflect" (potentiality vs. actuality). But let's wait and see what the OP will say.

Comment: @Araucaria-him That is exactly what I want to know! Sorry that I cause some misunderstandings.

Comment: @AlexB. You are right: a grammatical concept cannot always be defined by only one property. That is why I try to "test" for other grammatical properties.

Comment: @Guest1023854 Are you still visiting the site? If so, I'll write you an answer.

Comment: @Araucaria-him Yes, I am. Sorry for answering your question so late as I am not a regular visitor here. But I will be more attentive from now on.